# How to identify files which are not in list using bash?

Tags: bash, sh

Unfortunately my knowledge in bash not so well and I have very non-standard task.

I have a file with the files list.

Example: `/tmp/my/file1.txt /tmp/my/file2.txt`

How can I write a script which can check that files from folder `/tmp/my` exist and to have two types messages after script is done.

1 - Files exist and show files:

```
/tmp/my/file1.txt 
/tmp/my/file2.txt
```

2 - The folder `/tmp/my` including files and folders which are not in your list. The files and folders:

```
/tmp/my/test 
/tmp/my/1.txt
```

Comment: How is it not a "standard task", and what have you attempted?

Comment: Unsure as to what should be printed under what conditions, or if all existing and non-existing files should be printed, specially ordered or prefixed... could you clarify?

Comment: Hi, only existing. And it contains folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You speak of files and folders, which seems unclear.

Anyways, I wanted to try it with arrays, so here we go :

```
unset valid_paths; declare -a valid_paths
unset invalid_paths; declare -a invalid_paths
while read -r line
do
if [ -e "$line" ]
  then
    valid_paths=("${valid_paths[@]}" "$line")
  else
    invalid_paths=("${invalid_paths[@]}" "$line")
  fi
done < files.txt
echo "VALID PATHS:"; echo "${valid_paths[@]}"
echo "INVALID PATHS:"; echo "${invalid_paths[@]}"
```

Comment: OK. sorry. I can clarify: only files.

Comment: Then use `-f` in `test` instead of `-e`, as explained by  taifwa above.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the files' existence (assuming a list of files, one filename per line) and print the existing ones with a prefix using this

```
# Part 1 - check list contents for files
while read thefile; do
    if [[ -n "$thefile" ]] && [[ -f "/tmp/my/$thefile" ]]; then
        echo "Y: $thefile"
    else
        echo "N: $thefile"
    fi
done < filelist.txt | sort

# Part 2 - check existing files against list
for filepath in /tmp/my/* ; do
    filename="$(basename "$filepath")"
    grep "$filename" filelist.txt -q || echo "U: $filename"
done
```

The files that exist are prefixed here with `Y:`, all others are prefixed with `N:`

In the second section, files in the tmp directory that are not in the file list are labelled with `U:` (unaccounted for/unexpected)

You can swap the `-f` test which checks that a path exists and is a regular file for `-d` (exists and is a directory) or `-e` (exists)

See

```
man test
```

for more options.

Comment: Hi tried. I added only file1.txt and SEE:

Y: /tmp/my/file1.txt 

But I cant see:
N: /tmp/my/file2.txt

I see only:
N:

Comment: the N is matching an empty line. The script as above only checks for names on the list.

Comment: The updated example will also report what files were found that are not on the list.